# How to find a file in WordPress themes

Tags: themes, templates

I want to edit footer copyright section. How to know where is the file if the footer.php file doesn't contain full coding?

My theme footer.php file contains such do_action. Please explain me.

do_action( 'linten_action_footer' );
    ?>

Comment: do you wanna edit the section of  : created  with wordpress ?

Comment: Open your theme in your favorite code editor and then find this text `'linten_action_footer'` on the theme directory. Hopefully, you'll get what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your **Linten** WordPress theme in a text editor or IDE then open `inc/hook/custom.php` file, `inc` and `hook` is directory/folder. Then find this function `linten_footer_copyright` and do whatever you want to do. Here's the file link from WP theme repo -
 https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/linten/1.0.6/inc/hook/custom.php#L112

**How I found the right file**

Let me explain how I found your file.

You gave me this `do_action( 'linten_action_footer' );` and it's an important clue for me to figure the right file. From my 3 years experience, I know that WordPress recommend prefixing almost everything and prefix with theme-slug (in your case the slug is `linten`). So, I googled with the theme name and found that theme on WordPress theme repository and then downloaded the theme on my computer. Then opened the theme on my code editor and searched for `'linten_action_footer'`. From my experience, I also know that `do_action()` executes an action hook and `add_action()` registers an action hook. So, I've to find something like this `add_action( 'linten_action_footer'` and I found that. That's it!

If you're interested to learn more about action hooks then following links might help you.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/get-started-with-hooks-wordpress/
https://wpshout.com/wordpress-hooks-actions-filters-work/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: Your answer helped me to find the right page to edit, but I still need to know how did you determine or understand the right file? In this case always should be hook folder or can be a different folder name? I'll make this comment as correct answer. Please tell me the fundamentals of calling such shortcode. Thanks

Comment: I've added in details info of how I found your file. Please check

Comment: Note that changing theme code will cause problems if the theme ever gets updated. Better to make a Child Theme, then modify code in the Child Theme.

Answer (score 1):

Open your theme folder in any texteditor (Sublime text) and search for keyword `linten_action_footer`. You will find result pages containing the keyword. So from that you can choose the required

Comment: Thank for your comment, I know that technique, but want to know the core functionality of WordPress, the basic fundamentals of WP Themes development. Thanks

Comment: By searching as described above you will be able to find how footer page is completely structured. Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/find-function/ that use the reflection api of php to give the file that use a function.

PS: it is my plugin (I will bump the versions to avoid the annoying banner)

Comment: Your plugin's idea is excellent for not developer WP user. But, unfortunately it's not worked for me! I used staying in wp dashboard, theme edits, even in the footer.php but the same result couldn't find the path. Did I miss anything? See screenshot: https://imgur.com/uPMtYtO

Comment: The api doesn't support to find a function with parameters :-/ I will add a warning about it